# How to mark a Java library class as deprecated?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, deprecated

I have a library class, that is, a class that I load from a JAR, the source code is outside of my control. We instanciate it in our project in several places, and a property of the created objects should be always set. Unfortunately there is no central settings for the library, so I have created a subclass:

```
public class MyClass extends LibraryClass {
    public MyClass() {
        super();
        super.setSomeProperty();
    }
}
```

and then I replaced all instanciation of LibraryClass with MyClass. It works fine, but I want to prevent myself and my collegues to instanciate a LibraryClass in the future.

Is it possible to mark the LibraryClass (or its constructor) as deprecated by Maven or by Eclipse or somehow else?

Comment: You cant mark a third party class as deprecated for that you need to have source code as without compiling it's not possible.

Comment: Yes, I cannot mark a third party class as deprecated. But still, there are so many smart tools, perhaps one of them could result a simillar effect somehow. Any compiler warning would be helpful.

Comment: I would suggest one silly thing to you, you might try if you feel like doing so. Make a wrapper class to the library class you are using, now it's in your codebase, Do whatever you want to do with that class.

Comment: Ashutosh Sharma: I did first exactly what you have suggested. The question is the next step: how to prevent myself and my collegues to instanciate a LibraryClass in the future.

Comment: My answer will remain the same, I don't see any other solution than writing it somewhere as a standard that we will not use this library anymore.